# Does WCF works as SOAP by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, soap, asmx

Does WCF works as SOAP by default ?

As per client requirement, wanted to use ASMX web services. But VS 2013 not providing ASMX web services (SOAP) under 4.5.1 framework. So can I use WCF as SOAP? and How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can you WCF as SOAP you only need to add the bindings in client and server side you the basicHttpBinding binding

server side

```
<services>
  <service name="TestService">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ITestService"/>  
  </service>
</services>
```

client side add the service reference to your project

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://www.example.com/soap" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="ITestService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" />
  </client>
```

Answer (score 1):

But VS 2013 not providing ASMX web - this is  not correct !

how ever you can also add the ASMX service in 2013

use the WEB API its a RestFull service

[image]